# reverse this if-statement so it displays the image if both a video and image are uploaded, or the video if just video is uploaded

Tags: php

very quick newbie question. how do i reverse this if-statement so it displays the image if both a video and image are uploaded, or the video if just video is uploaded?

```
<?php if ( $video ) : ?>
<div class="feature_vid"><?php echo $video; ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="feature_img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-small' ); ?></a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the image variable is $image and you never want to show the video ever....

```
<?php 
    echo('<div class="feature_img"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . the_title_attribute());
 ?>
```